# Esconder Toolbar com CoordinatorLayout + TabLayout + ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

Bom dia, estou a tentar implementar as funcionalidades da google Material Design e queria esconder a Toolbar quando faço scroll na ViewPager (tem um RecyclerView dentro), no entanto não estou a conseguir o efeito pretendido (apesar de ter as tags todas necessárias no XML). Julgo que o problema seja o facto de ter a AppBar dentro de um LinearLayout (utilizei porque a ViewPAger ficava cortada em baixo e isso resolveu o problema), no entanto quando a tiro continua a não fazer o efeito pretendido. Envio os layouts em questão:

skeleton_view.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTeal200"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTeal500"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/gallery_fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_library_white_24px"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent700"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/camera_fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_white_24px"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent700"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent700"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.draft.meal.testing.ScrollFABAction.ScrollOffBottomBehaviour"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/view_pager"/>
```

skeleton.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:elevation="7dp"
tools:openDrawer="end"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_gravity="end">

<include layout="@layout/skeleton_view"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Exato, o `AppBarLayout` precisa ser filho direto do `CoordinatorLayout`. Está ocorrendo algum problema quando isso é feito?

Comment: Quando tiro o LinearLayout, também não faz o efeito de esconder a Toolbar. O LinearLayout só está lá para impedir que a ultima imagem (no RecyclerView do ViewPager) seja "recortada" em baixo. A aplicação corre normalmente tanto com ou sem LinearLayout, no entanto parece que não assume correctamente o scroll no fragmento do viewpager..